# Integrate a multivariate distribution to find its PMF

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

### Problem

The multinominal Dirichlet distribution is defined for probability vector $\mathbf{p}=[p_1,\cdots, p_d]^T$ with parameter $\alpha=[\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_d]^T$
$$
\pi(\mathbf{p})=\frac{\Gamma(|\alpha|)}{\prod_{j=1}^{d} \Gamma\left(\alpha_{j}\right)} \prod_{j=1}^{d} p_{j}^{\alpha_{j}-1}
$$
where $\vert\alpha\vert=\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_i$

Now for vector $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\cdots,x_n]^T$ where each $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=16$, find its PMF under multinominal Dirichlet distribution.

### What I Have Done

It is not difficult to write a general form formula
$$
f(\mathbf{x} | \alpha)=\int_{\Delta_{d}} \left( \begin{array}{c}{\sum_{i=1}^dx_i} \\ {\mathbf{x}}\end{array}\right) \prod_{j=1}^{d} p_{j}^{x_{j}} \pi(\mathbf{p}) d \mathbf{p}
$$
where $\Delta d$ is a unit simplex.

However, I am doubtful if this could actually give a closed-form formula. More specifically, I am not sure how to deal with vector $\mathbf{p}$ and product in the integrand.

### Solution

The PMF result is available on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution). For those who interested in derivation, a complete derivation could be found [here](https://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/info6150/exercises/polya.pdf).

Comment: In what way does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution not solve your problem?

Comment: @kimchilover I checked the Wikipedia page, it does give the PMF I anticipate. But I am wondering how they actually derive this formula.

Comment: If you know how to calculate the norming constant for the Dirichlet, you know how to find the expectation of $\Pi p_i^{x_i}$: the $x_i$ are simply added to the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you. I just realized this. I think I was scared by the form it looks like.